# Modified compressed sparse row matrix code

Tags: c++, matrix, compression

I've implemented a Modified Compressed Sparse Row matrix class! The class works, but I think that some part of the code is quite crap. There are two passages and the whole code became too expansive ... here I report the principal part for which I have some doubt about elegance and is resources consuming:

```
 template <typename element_type>
class MSRmatrix {

  public:

   using itype = std::size_t ;  

   template <typename T>
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os ,const MSRmatrix<T>& m) noexcept ;

   template <typename T>
   friend MSRmatrix<T> operator+(const MSRmatrix<T>& m1, const MSRmatrix<T>& m2) ;   


  public:

   constexpr MSRmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::vector<element_type>> row) noexcept; 

   constexpr MSRmatrix( std::string ) noexcept; 

   constexpr MSRmatrix( std::size_t ) noexcept; 

   auto constexpr printMSR()const noexcept ;

   std::size_t constexpr findIndex(const itype, const itype) const noexcept ;

   const element_type operator()(const itype, const itype) const noexcept ;

   element_type operator()(const itype, const itype) noexcept ;

   auto operator()(const itype, const itype,const element_type val) noexcept ;

   auto constexpr print() const noexcept ;   

   auto constexpr toFile(std::string) noexcept ;   

   inline auto constexpr nnz() const noexcept { return aa_.size(); }

   inline auto constexpr Dim() const noexcept { return dim ; }
  private:

   itype dim ;  


   std::vector<itype>         ja_ ;   
   std::vector<element_type>  aa_ ;   

   enum value{ stars };

};


template <typename T>
constexpr MSRmatrix<T>::MSRmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>> row ) noexcept  : dim{row.size()}
{     
      this->dim = row.size() ;
      auto il = *(row.begin()) ;

      if(this-> dim != il.size())
      {
         std::cerr << "Matrix contained into MSRmatrix format must be square!" << std::endl;    
         exit(-1);   
      }
      std::vector<std::vector<T>> temp(row);

      itype i=0 , j=0 , w=0 , k=0, z=dim;

      this->aa_.resize(dim+1);
      this->ja_.resize(dim+1);

      for(auto& x : row)
      {   
          j=0 ; k=0 ; 
          for(auto& y : x)
          {
             if(i==j) 
             {
                  aa_.at(i) = y ;
             }
             if(i != j && y != 0 ) 
             { 
                aa_.push_back(y);
                z++ ;
                ja_.push_back(j+1);
                if( k==0 )
                { 
                   ja_[w] = z+1; 
                   w++ ;
                   k++ ;
                }
             }
             j++ ;     
          }
          i++ ;  
      }
      while(w <= dim)
      {   
          ja_[w] = z+2 ;  
          w++ ;  
      }

# ifdef __DEBUG__
    printMSR();  
# endif
}
```

The following method is written to find the index in the original matrix and has the possibility to print out the matrix [(reference here)](http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/wagner/node83.html)

```
template <typename T>
std::size_t constexpr MSRmatrix<T>::findIndex(const itype row ,  const itype col) const noexcept 
{    
     assert( row > 0 && row <= dim && col > 0 && col <= dim ); 
     if(row == col)
     {
       return row-1;
     }
      itype i = -1;


      if( row == dim )// == ja_.at(row) ) // last row
      {
            i= (ja_.at(row-1)-1) ;


            if(ja_.at(i-1) == col)
              return i-1;
      }

      for(itype i = ja_.at(row-1)-1 ; i < ja_.at(row)-1 ; i++ )
      {
            if( ja_.at(i) == col ) 
            { 
              return i;
            }
      }
      return -1;
}
```

and the last thing, which I think is the most important one, is the method written to insert an element into the matrix. I want to improve it.

```
template <typename T>
auto MSRmatrix<T>::operator()(const itype r, const itype c, const T val) noexcept
{    

   if(val != 0)
   {
     auto i = findIndex(r,c);
     if(i != -1 && i < nnz())
     {     

            aa_.at(i) = val;
     }
     else
     {
        if(r==c)
        {
            aa_.at(r) = val ; // the size doesn't change
        }
        else if( r != c )
        {   
            if( ja_.at(r-1) == ja_.at(r) ) // last line ;
            {     
                  ja_.at(r) += 1 ;

                  i = ja_.at(r-1)-1;
                  ja_.insert(ja_.begin() + i , c  ); 
                  aa_.insert(aa_.begin() + i , val);
            }
            else   // general line
            {
                  for(auto i = ja_.at(r-1)-1 ; i < ja_.at(r)-1 ; i++ )
                  {
                       if( ja_.at(i) == c  )
                       {    
                               aa_.at(i) = val ;
                       }
                       else
                       {     
                            for(auto ii = r ; ii < dim+1 ; ii++ )   
                            {
                              ja_.at(ii) +=1 ;
                            }  
                              ja_.insert(ja_.begin() + i , c  ); 
                              aa_.insert(aa_.begin() + i , val);
                              break;
                       }
                     //std::cout << ja_.at(r) << std::endl ;
                  }
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

in operator() i return T instead of const T& because if the element is not found it return 0 that is a rvalue !

Answer (score 2):

## Missing headers

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

---

## Interface

- I don't think `operator<<()` can be `noexcept`, unless you're not using the `std::ostream` argument!
- Is there a good reason that the `initializer_list` constructor requires `std::vector` arguments?  The code only requires arguments that are enumerable with range-based `for`.
- I don't think the `findIndex()` method ought to be public.  It's an implementation detail that client code shouldn't need to be aware of; making it public may be a sign of missing functionality that clients need.  I don't know if `Dim()` and `nnz()` need to be public, but either way, they could have better names.
- Consider making `operator()()` return a (possibly const-qualified) reference, to make the interface more like standard collections.
- The return types of public methods should be complete (`auto` without a trailing return type prevents the methods being called before their definitions are in scope).
- There's no benefit to `const` on arguments passed by value in the interface.  Go ahead and use them in the definitions, of course:

  ```
  class MSRmatrix
  {
  public:
      // declaration
      const element_type& operator()(itype, itype) const noexcept;
  };

  // definition
  const element_type& MSRmatrix::operator()(const itype, const itype) const noexcept
  {
      // code...
  }
  ```
- It's probably worth declaring `using value_type = element_type` like the standard containers - it makes it easier to use in generic code.  And consider  renaming `itype` to `size_type` for the same reason.
- It should be possible to implement `print()` and `toFile()` as non-member non-friend functions.  If not, consider adding suitable public methods to implement them.
- `operator+()` wouldn't need to be a friend if you provide `operator+=` as a member.
- The `value` enum is never used.

---

## Implementation

### Constructor

- Don't `exit()` from within the constructor.  Prefer to throw an exception instead - that way the calling code can choose whether to emit output (and if so, by what means) and whether it can recover from the error.
- There's a redundant assignment `this->dim = row.size()` - the initializer has done its job by the time we get here.
- The `temp` vector is assigned but never used.
- The index variables can be declared with smaller scope.

Comment: Heh. `operator+` will be (slightly) faster than `operator+=` in this case. Thanks for the two typo fixes by the way.

Comment: in operator() i return T instead of const T& because if the element is not found it return 0 that is a rvalue !

Comment: That makes sense @Marco - I misunderstood that it might insert a new value and return that.  With the additional knowledge, I'd suggest renaming to `at()` to help guide the reader by analogy.

Answer (score 2):

## Rethink design decisions

> [T]he most important one [..] is the method [..] to insert an element into the matrix.

It isn't. The CSR format is not meant for easy insertion or modification in general. The CSR format is meant for \$\mathcal O(n) \$ matrix vector multiplication. The same holds for the MCSR format.

The sparse matrices are usually a result of a finite element approach: after the initial triangulation only some vertices/edges/faces/nodes will be coupled to others. This leads to a sparse matrix where only some elements will even interact with others. It leads to a *single* sparse matrix, that *won't get changed* afterwards.

A modification of a matrix in (M)CSR format will *always* lead to problems, since the sequential memory has to be moved, leading from an `insert` that should take \$\mathcal O(1)\$ to an operation that will take \$\mathcal O(n)\$. It's better to use another format for the intermediate manipulation, like DOK* or LIL, especially if you have many insertions. This can change a \$\mathcal O(kn)\$ algorithm into a \$\mathcal O(k*\log(n) + 2n)\$.

Again, the CSR format isn't meant for modification. Don't take my word, though, ask [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix):

> #### Advantages of the CSR format
>
> - efficient arithmetic operations CSR + CSR, CSR * CSR, etc.
> - efficient row slicing
> - fast matrix vector products
>
> #### Disadvantages of the CSR format
>
> - slow column slicing operations (consider CSC)
> - ***changes to the sparsity structure are expensive (consider LIL or DOK)***

Therefore, you should change your class design at that point, unless you want to keep your matrix modifiable. It heavily depends on your use case, but if you want to modify your matrix often, then CSC or CSR are the wrong tools.

## Use better names

That being said, `ja_` and `aa_` are possibly two of the worst names you could come up with for members. If you have a look at your code in 3 months you won't remember whether `ja_` was a bunch of indices. Give them proper names, like `values_` and `index_` for example. You can probably come up with better ones.

## Consider `std::ostream&` for output functions.

All your print functions may be eligible to use a `std::ostream`, but that's not clear from the code you've shown. That way you can re-use functionality, by the way.

## Use call by value when you change the value, call by reference otherwise

Prefer `const T&` instead of `T` as an argument, *unless* you change the value in your function. I'm talking about your `std::string` constructor for example. Since you didn't include the implementation it's not clear whether call by value is needed there.

This only holds for complex values, of course, not for basic types.

---

<sup>* DOK is plain simple in C++, by the way, you might want to implement it as an exercise.</sup>

Comment: Is linear time matrix multiplication possible? I've read that due to cache misses it degrades pretty quickly.

Comment: @Incomputable linear time matrix-matrix multiplication isn't possible, unless you mean pointwise.

Comment: I see, it probably was about amount of cache misses.

Comment: @Incomputable I'm slightly confused. Did you mean "linear time matrix-matrix multiplication", "linear time matrix-vector multiplication" or "linear time pointwise matrix-matrix multiplication"? Two of them are possible in linear time, where the number of cache misses is bound be the number of non-zero elements per row divided by the cache size.

Comment: in operator() i return T instead of const T& because if the element is not found it return 0 that is a rvalue ! –

Comment: @MarcoGhiani I didn't even comment on that. I've commented on ___arguments___. "Call by value/reference". I didn't comment on return values at all.

Comment: @Zeta, I meant cross-product in linear time. It seems like it is indeed about time complexity, but [the article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm) seems to mention tight bound.

Comment: @Zeta efficient arithmetic operations CSR + CSR, CSR * CSR where i can found the algorithm ??

Comment: @MarcoGhiani In SciPy, for example. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L768-L856. I've linked the class from SciPy, by the way, you just have to follow its documentation to the source to find the algorithm.

Comment: @Incomputable man, the language barrier hits hard this evening, sorry. A vector cross-product? Or the usual [matrix matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm)? Either way, I can construct two CSR matrices \$A\$ and \$B\$ that both have only \$n\$ nonzero entries, such that the result \$AB\$ will have \$n^2\$ entries.

Comment: @Zeta, I'm talking about simple matrix product, where the (i, j)th entry is the sum of multiplication of ith row of A and jth column of B. The matrices I assumed were trivial ones, e.g. just contiguously allocated ones and aligned properly. I thought that getting one entry is assumed as constant time, and complexity would rise from slowing down each entry calculation, but it seems like wikipedia used your model too.

Comment: where i can found an implementations of the MSR method well done in C++ ?? I mean ModCSR not CSR